# Regex- to extract a string before and after string

Tags: regex, dynatrace

Want extract string before and after the word. Below are the content.

Content:

```
1. http://www.example.com/myplan/mp/public/pl_be?Id=543543&timestamp=06280435435

2. http://www.example.com/course/df/public/pl_de?Id=454354&timestamp=0628031746

3. http://www.example.com/book/rg/public/pl_fo?Id=4445577&timestamp=0628031734

4. http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/pl_ds?Id=454354&timestamp=06280314546

5. http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/pl_ds
```

I want capture data for above string as below

```
1. http://www.example.com/myplan/mp/public/?Id=543543

2. http://www.example.com/course/df/public/?Id=454354

3. http://www.example.com/book/rg/public/?Id=4445577

4. http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/?Id=454354

5. http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/
```

I have tried with **(.*/(?![A-Za-z]{2}_[A-Za-z]{2}).*(?=&))**. But it won't help.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will catch what you want in two groups. It's more safe than other other examples that have been suggested so far because it allows for some variance in the URL.

`(.*)\w\w_\w\w.*?(?:(?:[&?]\w+=\d+|%\w*)*?(\?Id=\d+)(?:.*))?`

- `(.*)` captures everything up until your xx_xx part (capture group 1)
- `\w\w_\w\w.*` matches xx_xx and everything up until the next capture section
- `(?:[&?]\w+=\d+|%\w*)*?` allows for there to be other & % or ? properties in your URL before your `?Id=` property
- `(\?Id=\d+)` captures your Id property (capture group 2)
- `(?:.*)` is unnecessary but it bugs me when not all of the text is highlighted on regex101 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
- the optional non-capturing group here `(?:(?:[&?]\w+=\d+|%\w*)*?(\?Id=\d+)(?:.*))?` allows it to match URLs that don't have ID properties.

[Here's an example of how it works](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/10)

Answer (score 0):

## **Response updated:**

This pattern will do the work for you:

`(.*\/)[^?]*(?:(\?[^&]*).*)?`

**Explanation:**

`(.*\/)` -> Will match and capture every character until the `/` character is present (The .* is a greedy operator).

`[^?]*`  -> Will match everything that's not a `?` character.

`(?:(\?[^&]*).*)?` -> First of all, `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group, the `?` at the end of this makes this group optional, `(\?[^&]*)` will match and capture the `?` character and every non `&` character next to it, the last `.*` will match everything after the first param in the URL.

Then you can replace the string using only the first and second capture groups.

[Here is a working example in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yyFD6q/3/)

**Edit 2:**

As **emsimpson92** mentioned in the comments, the Id couldn't always be the first param, so you can use this pattern to match the Id param:

`(.*\/)[^?]*(?:(\?).*?(Id=[^&]*).*)?`

The important part here is that `.*?(Id=[^&]*).*` matches the Id param no matter its position.

`.*?` -> It matches all the characters until `Id=` is present. The trick here is that `.*` is a greedy quantifier but when is used in conjunction with `?` it becomes a lazy one.

[Here is an Example of this scenario in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yyFD6q/4)

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo.
Sometime url might have multiple parameters like as 

http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/pl_ds?Id=454354&timestamp=06280314546&bid=7667&source=ref

Will it possible to get the string till FIRST '&' (only first parameter value) 

like as 'http://www.example.com/trip/tr/public/pl_ds?Id=454354'

Thanks,

Comment: Please let me know if the explanation is clear enough

Comment: This can be easily broken if the URL format varies. I've included an update in my answer in case this sort of thing might happen.

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira I believe the OP wanted to exclude the `&timestamp` portion as well.

Comment: @NitinD I've updated the response as you requested in your first comment, sorry for the late response